# How to remove unwanted data from python panda data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After reading my txt file:  https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/multiclass/glass.scale

The panda datadframe like as below:

```
1                 2                     3      4            

-0.4302012 2     -0.3233208 3    0.576837 4   0.426791 5
```

But I need the data as below( Space and extra letter should be removed)

```
1                 2                     3      4            

-0.4302012      -0.3233208     0.576837   0.426791
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer: Thanks for all trying

```
data = pd.read_csv(filepath,delimiter=':',header= None)
data = data.drop([0],axis=1)
for i in range(1,9):
   search_string = str(i+1)
   data[i] = data[i].map(lambda x: x.replace(search_string.rjust(1),''))
print(data)
data.sample(n=5)
```